# Mixing JPA Entity with Grails GORM Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, grails, grails-orm

An existing Grails project needs to reuse some JPA entities and cross references between the GORM and JPA entities are required. I ran into some problems when trying to do a one-to-many from GORM entity to JPA. Below is an example:

GORM Entity:

```
class Person {
   String firstName

   static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
   static mappedBy = [addresses: 'person']

   static mapping = {
      firstName column: 'First_Name'
      addresses column: 'person_id'
  }
}
```

JPA Entity

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="num")
    private String number;

    @Column(name="code")
    private String postCode;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getPostCode() {
        return postCode;
    }
    public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person getPerson(){
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person){
        this.person = person;
    }


 }
```

Hibernate Mapping

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       <mapping package="test" />
       <mapping class="test.Address" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Exception on startup

```
Caused by MappingException: Missing type or column for 
column[addresses_address] on domain[Person] referencing[test.Address]
```

The mappedBy does not seem to make any difference and the 'addresses' column name appears to be ignored.

If both the Person and Address class are GORM entities then it works without issues.

The project uses Grails 2.1.5. Is reference of JPA entities from GORM possible?

Thanks in advance